# Assetic and Silex - debug mode

Tags: php, silex, assetic

First Stackoverflow question. UHUH!

Silex-Assetic as doing my head in.

Following the docs on https://github.com/mheap/Silex-Assetic/blob/master/doc/assetic.rst and the demo on https://github.com/mheap/Silex-Assetic-Demo I ended up with this:

```
$app->register(new SilexAssetic\AsseticServiceProvider());

$app['assetic.path_to_web'] = __DIR__ . '/assets/min';
$app['assetic.options'] = array(
    'debug'              => true,
    'auto_dump_assets'  => true
);

$app['assetic.filter_manager'] = $app->share(
$app->extend('assetic.filter_manager', function($fm, $app) {
        $fm->set('yui_css', new Assetic\Filter\Yui\CssCompressorFilter(
            __DIR__ . '/../yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar'
        ));
        $fm->set('yui_js', new Assetic\Filter\Yui\JsCompressorFilter(
            __DIR__ . '/../yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar'
        ));

        return $fm;
    })
);

$app['assetic.asset_manager'] = $app->share(
    $app->extend('assetic.asset_manager', function($am, $app) {
        $am->set('dragons', new Assetic\Asset\AssetCache(
            new Assetic\Asset\GlobAsset(
                __DIR__ . '/assets/css/*.css',
                array($app['assetic.filter_manager']->get('yui_css'))
            ),
            new Assetic\Cache\FilesystemCache(__DIR__ . '/../cache/assetic')
        ));
        $am->get('dragons')->setTargetPath('dragons-min.css');

        return $am;
    })
);
```

And, on my twig file:

```
{% stylesheets '../../assets/css/*.css' filter='yui_css' output='/assets/min/dragons-min.css' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I'm having two problems:

- Somehow I end with the a dragons-min.css file in `/assets/min/dragons-min.css` AND on `/assets/min/assets/min/dragons-min.css`
- If I enable debug mode, I end up with weird files.

Like this:

```
<link href="/assets/min/dragons-min_part_1_bootstrap.min_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/min/dragons-min_part_1_main_2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/min/dragons-min_part_1_normalize_3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If debug mode is off, I would like to be calling the original files on `/assets/css`. And also not to end up with a duplicated directory structure.

The documentation is VERY bad at this stage and I'm a bit new with Silex too. I would love to have my structure and code challenged by you. :)

Comment: have you tried the output parameter without the leading /

Comment: @gunnx Just did. No luck.

Comment: try setting path_to_web to just `__DIR__`

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this repo, it is a much better example of how to integrate the AsseticServiceProvider.
https://github.com/lyrixx/Silex-Kitchen-Edition

Comment: I don't see any Assetic setup in the project you mention, @Failpunk